# Application crash when changing package name

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a project in android studio that works very well but when I change my package name and applicationId, my project crashes.

**Error:**

```
No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Comment: check your MainActivity on top package name is correct

Comment: _No adapter attached; skipping layout_ This is not what is causing the crash. This is generated when using a [`RecylcerView`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29141729/450534)

Answer (score 2):

Use refactoring (Shift + F6) instead of renaming the package manually.
Make sure your settings.gradle is correct ( change include ':app' to new name ). Invalidate cache and restart Android-Studio. Rebuild your project. It should work then.

Comment: i see this error by this method: Failed to find provider info for com.example.newname

Comment: what's your new packagename? show some code ....

Comment: my first package name was: com.tellme.tellme. second name is: com.tell.bot. in gradle applicationId was: com.tellme.tellme and now is: com.tellme.bot. note is here i see this error:  Failed to find provider info for com.bot.bot!!!!!

Comment: do not have any idea?

Comment: open the java class file(s) and press  CTRL + ALT + O  to fix imports. Maybe due to refactoring package names imports are wrong or missing. (This is a good read: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/packages-in-java/ )